# Automatically disable (and resume) from exceptions in Java

Tags: java, exception

I would like to know how is it possible to disable unchecked exceptions in Java and instead print out an error to the console and skip to the very next method in the class where the exception was thrown from.

Comment: Application should be designed in such a way that I never produces unchecked exception at run-time. You need to handle all the cases such as `NullPointerException`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` using proper checks.

Comment: What was the benevolent down vote for?

Comment: Application design is independent of Unchecked exception. Can you design a software that prevents a remote server from going down or returning a 404 error when you anticipate a content containing webpage?

Comment: @IsraelCohen If you're using or designing an API that throws an unchecked exception on a condition like a error 404 or a remote server being down, please reconsider your design or write an adapter that rethrows a checked exception. These examples are not good reasons to throw an unchecked exception.

Comment: @IsraelCohen Being an [unchecked exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) is not directly related to the task/process described.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable exception induced suppression in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397720/how-to-disable-exception-induced-suppression-in-java)

Comment: Looks like a direct duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397720/how-to-disable-exception-induced-suppression-in-java)?

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing the [JVM Specification, 2.10. Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10):

> An exception in the Java Virtual Machine is represented by an instance of the class Throwable or one of its subclasses. Throwing an exception results in an immediate nonlocal transfer of control from the point where the exception was thrown.

In other words, no matter what you do, any `Exception` thrown results in a control transfer, not allowing you to continue as if it never happened.

Comment: Thanks. But is it a good idea to use reflection to get the list of all classes and re-run the classes(methods of classes more precisely) which had not been executed previously? Like define a static Integer in every class. Upon program execution set every Integer in every class to 0, once entering into the class, change the Integer to 1, upon any exception throwing iterate over all classes and execute the methods of classes where the integer is still set to zero(meaning, there were no entries into the class up to the time when the exception was thrown)Do you think there is a better way?

Comment: @IsraelCohen You _probably_ could use some functor type and roll your own style of control flow, but you wouldn't be able to change the fundamentals of the JVM. _What is your use case here? Why do you want to do this?_

Answer (score 1):

There's no `On Error Resume Next` (or whatever it is) like in Visual Basic. If there's an error, it needs to be handled somehow, not just automatically assume that a program will work properly.

A full suite of unit tests is a good way to check that common unchecked exceptions like null  pointers or `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions` don't occur.